# How to add a library to an Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to add a Library to Eclipse Galileo and it won't work out.

Library: gdi32.lib -> In MinGW: libgdi32.a

Whatever I try, it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me EXACTLY what to enter where, to accomplish this ?

Details:

I have the function call:

```
wndclassex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

... lead's to error:

```
WinMain.o: In function `WinMain':
Z:/mtsts_workspace/MTSTS/Debug/../WinMain.c:29: 
  undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
```

And I have the function call:

```
TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, TEXT("Hello World!"), 12);
```

... lead's to error:

```
WinMain.o: In function `WndProc':
Z:/mtsts_workspace/MTSTS/Debug/../WinMain.c:88: 
  undefined reference to `TextOutA@20'
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, please could you append it to your question?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

right click to project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build, go to Library and add it there.

if the library is `libgdi32.a`, you should add `gdi32` in the library section.

Comment: Thank you ! What I didn't know, was that to use libgdi32.a you have to enter gdi32 !

Comment: In the sequence of steps two steps are missing: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries

Comment: The current CDT menu interface is completely different and I have yet to find the correct information. I want to link with libxcb, which normally you would do with -lxcb. From the command line, that's the only thing I have to add. I have Eclipse CDT Juno version. C/C++ Build -> Settings doesn't have such settings, it only has "binary parsers." I have attempted to add it to C/C++ Build -> Paths and Symbols, Libraries tab, but that doesn't affect the Makefile, so it must be the wrong place.

Answer (score 7):

If on eclipse 3.5 the place to add is
project->properties->C++ Build->Settings
Then choose the tool chain you are using then in Libraries and add the library name to the top box and the path to the bottom

Comment: Is there a standard place where the name of the library (that which must be added at the top) is specified? i.e. how does one know that glut32.lib is "glut32" and libgdi32.a is "gdi32" ?

Comment: Depends on OS - Windows is name.lib and unix is libnam.so or libname.a or libname.dylib

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem. As Mark suggested,   in project->properties->C++ Build->Settings, we have to add

1) library name (for eg: libsnap7.so, only snap7 is the name)
2) library path (eg: /usr/lib)

Problem remained unsolved till I do this.