# How to use my library in C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, shared-libraries, static-libraries

In Eclipse I have created two libraries. One of them is shared another one is static. I have compiled them in Eclipse and as a result a Debug folder was created (for both libraries) and these folders contain make-files as well as object files (*.o) and dependency reference file (*.d). In addition to that, the static library contains an *.a file.

Now I create a new project and what to use these library in this project. Normally, when I use a library I type `#include <libraryname>`. But if I use `#include <mylibraryname>` it does not work (I get unresolved inclusion). And this is not surprising because Eclipse should somehow know where my library is located. So, my question is how can I inform Eclipse about the locations of my libraries.

**ADDED** As recommended I do the following sequence "Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries". Then, in the "libraries(-l)" filed I add "StaticList" (because I have "libStaticList.a" file) and in the "Library search path (-L)" filed I give the full name of the directory where my "libStaticList.a" is located. Then I click Apply and OK. But it does not help. Eclipse does not like `#include <StaticList>`. It complains: "Unresolved Inclusion..".

Comment: does [this](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include`ing headers only makes the compiler aware that the functions in those headers exist. The actual *implementation* of those functions needs to be linked in by the linker. That's where the library (`.a`) files that you built come in. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351712/how-to-add-a-library-to-an-eclipse-project) for an example on how to link in your libraries using Eclipse.

Comment: the link to the thread, that you gave looks very relevant to my question. However, when I do what is recommended in this thread, my problem still remains (for more details you can see the new/extended version of my question).

Comment: Back up a tick - does the build process fail during compilation and indicate an error on the line where you `#include` the header, or does it fail during linking?

Comment: as a result of Build I get: "StaticList: data or folder are not found". StaticList is the name of the library that I am trying to use.

Comment: You said `#include <StaticList>` fails. Shouldn't it be `#include <StaticList.h>`? You should be including the header file(s) for your library. The library itself is linked in by the linker, not `#include`d

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to #include "yourlibrary.cpp" (between double quotes) instead of < >.

Comment: if I include cpp files, it works but I wanted to learn how to use libraries. I wanted to compile MyLibrary.cpp and Main.cpp independently.