# Add library to C/c++ eclipse indigo project

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am trying to add a library to C/C++ project in `Eclipse` by the following procedure:

1. Properties->C/C++General->includes (within includes specifying the folder in which the library is kept).
2. Properties->C/C++General->Library Paths (Specifying the library paths of .so and .a files)
3. Properties->C/C++General->Libraries (Specifying adding paths of .so and .a files)

But when I build the project,it is not able to find the path of header files that I am including in my project.

Can someone please tell me where the error is?

[image]

Comment: I take it that your eclipse has the CDT installed? have you tried adding the path to the linker. Because an .a file is needed by the linker. You can do so by adding a -l(name.a) (without lib) to the linker flags

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351712/how-to-add-a-library-to-an-eclipse-project). You need to add the libraries in the Properties -> C/C++ -> Build area, not the General area.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But which option in the Build Area should I use. The options which I am getting in the build are as shown in the edit

Comment: Hope that you'll help..I am really stuck with this.