# Adding a library to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse and I could not solve this problem.

How could I import [this](https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView) library to Eclipse using the default builder (not using Gradle)?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but I would suggest you to use Android Studio instead. As time passes by, the support for Eclipse decreases even more. [Here](http://codetutr.com/2013/03/23/how-to-import-gradle-project-into-eclipse/) is a tutorial that might help you solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a library to an Eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351712/how-to-add-a-library-to-an-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using Gradle/Maven and using Eclipse you need to manually add the library.

The library is in the jcenter repository, which means there is a jar file available. This jar file can be found [here](https://dl.bintray.com/isseiaoki/maven/com/isseiaoki/simplecropview/1.0.13/) (I'm pretty sure you need the `-sources.jar`)

Download this library and save it in a logical place. Go to Eclipse, highlight the project and press `Alt+Enter`. Go to the `Java Build Path` page and click `Add External JARs` under the `Libraries` tab. Select the JAR file and it should be fine.

Keep in mind that the Eclipse ADT plugin is not the way Google wants you to do it. If you have no reason to use Eclipse other than that it's what you have set up now, you should probably move to Android Studio.

Comment: Yes .thanks for help. but I can't get Classes maybe you know why ?

Comment: I could use  import com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.*; but inside I don't have any class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project and add github version project files to newly created project else download the entire project from github and add this project to your current project.

right click(current project) -> Build path -> Configure build path -> Java build path -> Projects (tab) -> click add

Just add this project there and build your project.