# compile time error in Eclipse: "undefined reference to `sctp_recvmsg'"

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, sctp

How to build SCTP client.c and server.c sample code with Eclipse in Linux ubuntu?

In terminal I can build with

```
gcc -Wall sctpclient.c -lsctp -o sctpclient
```

but in Eclipse I received "undefined reference to `sctp_recvmsg'".

I don't know to add the "-lsctp" switch in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: _[How to set compiler settings in Eclipse](https://codeyarns.com/2014/01/14/how-to-change-compiler-options-of-build-in-eclipse-cdt/)_

Comment: Project properties->C/C++ General->Paths and symbols

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a library to an Eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351712/how-to-add-a-library-to-an-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right path in Eclipse IDE, You must add -lsctp parameter to below path:

```
Project properties->C/C++ Build->Setting->GCC C Linker->Miscellaneous->Other objects
```

And in NetBeans IDE add parameter to:

```
Project properties->Build->Linker->Additional Options
```