# Adding dlib to C++ eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, linker, dlib

I am trying to add dlib library to eclipse. I downloaded dlib from http://dlib.net/ and copied the dlib folder into my project folder.

Then I do the following:

(1) Project -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols
(2) Choose GNU C++ 
(3) Choose Add 
(4) Choose Variables
(5) Type "ProjDirPath"

I copy the code from http://dlib.net/optimization_ex.cpp.html into a source file. Everything seems okay (i.e. nothing underlined in red).

I try build the file and I get:

Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:/Users/..." -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\main.cpp" 
In file included from c:...
...
...
"
Is there something I am doing wrong? Why cannot I not run the code on their website?

I have also tried adding the dlib library as follows (same as here [How to add a library to an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351712/how-to-add-a-library-to-an-eclipse-project))

(1) Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries

(2) I add dlib to the top (Libraries(-l)) and the location of the dlib folder library at the bottom (Libraries(-L)).

I then get the error

Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-LC:\Users..." -o myfile.exe main.o -ldlib 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldlib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Finally, I'll mention that I'm new to C++.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to C++ you should use cmake to generate your project.  If you type something like this:

```
cd dlib/examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ..
```

cmake will create an Eclipse project for you that will be correctly configured.  CMake can generate a lot of different project types.  If you type `cmake -h` you will see a list of "generators" supported by cmake like visual studio, sublime text, etc.

Writing CMake configure files is also very easy.  The one for the dlib examples serves double purpose as a simple cmake tutorial and is worth looking at: http://dlib.net/examples/CMakeLists.txt.html

Comment: No problem.  I should also point out that visual studio is probably a less frustrating IDE, on windows, than eclipse.  Visual studio is also free.  I would get "visual studio 2015 community" since it's free and has the best C++11 support, better than visual studio 2017 surprisingly.