# Yocto project how to add a library to Eclipse with Yocto Plugin

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded-linux, yocto

(Please do not scold me, this is my first question here.)

I'm using Yocto 2.3.1 under Ubuntu. I create image for Raspebrry Pi 3 without any problem. I install Eclipse and yocto-plugin for Eclipse. I create HelloWorld Autotools project and debug it on target hardware - no problems.
But, when I try to add some library, besides standart stdlib.h and stdio.h, I get "undefined reference to 'name'" Where I can add a library to Eclipse with Yocto Plugin? I can't find this place!

Source: %)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dbm.h>

int main(void){
 char fn = "someFile";
 dbminit(&fn);
 return 0;
}
```

Toolchain Root Location: /opt/poky/2.3.1/

Sysroot Location: /opt/poky/2.3.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi

(I'm using SDK for my image)

Thanks in advance.

UPD:

[image: Project settings]

Comment: In the eclipse project settings, you didn't find anything about a library path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351712/how-to-add-a-library-to-an-eclipse-project

Comment: I added project settings screenshot. Unfortunately, the project settings are very poor. I did not find a place where I can specify the used libraries.In some places, on the NXP forums, people talk about making a path to the libraries in the Makefile.am file. But it did not work either.

Comment: I think you need the CDT plugin http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Adding_C.2FC.2B.2B_External_Libraries

Comment: Definitely, I installed exactly Eclipse CDT. And when I creating a project for the host system, I can easily add any library. Build -> Settings -> etc. The problem only with projects for Yocto. And thanks for your help with the formatting.

Comment: My point is that the CDT plugin is what allows you to add libraries. I don't see how this yocto plugin would affect that. I've not used it, though

Comment: Unfortunately, when you create a project from yocto-template, the ability to add libraries in the usual way disappears. Or I do not understand something.
In any case, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before and I solved it by adding needed libraries in Makefile.am file (in the same directory of the source code) to AM_LDFLAGS = ...

here is an example of how the Makefile.am file looks like after adding two OpenCV libraries:

```js
bin_PROGRAMS = nxp
nxp_SOURCES = nxp.cpp

AM_CXXFLAGS = @nxp_CFLAGS@
AM_LDFLAGS = @nxp_LIBS@ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc 

CLEANFILES = *~
```

save changes, then right click on the project and choose Reconfigure Project before building.