# #include At packages are marked unresolved conclusions

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

I have a fairly large Qt Gui application that I want to try debugging using the Eclipse IDE. I have all the source code loaded up into Eclipse but the includes for Qt are erring out:

```
#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QSplashScreen>
#include <QPlastiqueStyle>
#include <QResource>
#include <QWSEvent>
```

When highlighting the errors the IDE is telling me that the includes above are unresolved conclusions. I am new to Eclipse but I am assuming this means that the compiler can't find the packages?

So that leads me into my question. How do I include these packages or how do I get Eclipse to communicate with Qt?

Comment: Have you told it *where* to find the headers?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351712/how-to-add-a-library-to-an-eclipse-project

Comment: @Jesper Juhl No I don't believe so. Tbh I am not sure where they are located.

Comment: And there's your problem.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl So I think I have found them in Qt-4.72/include/QtGui but how do I tell Eclipse where to go looking for them?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah I saw that but I can't seem to find anything related to Qt in: The Eclipse Project Updates - ttp://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.8 or Photon - ttp://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon